# Need to select columns from excel and write to another excel using python pandas is not working

Tags: python-3.x

Please find the below code and let me know why the output excel is not having the columns from the input excel.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
from datetime import date
import xlrd
import glob
import csv
import openpyxl
import asposecells
import aspose
from aspose import Workbook
today = date.today()
file_loc = str(r"C://Users//" +str(os.getenv('username')) + r"//Downloads//Enterprise Jira AWS " + str(today) + "*.xls")
actual_file = glob.glob(file_loc)
file_sel = str(actual_file[len(actual_file) - 1])
print(actual_file)
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_sel)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
filename = str(r"C://Users//" +str(os.getenv('username')) + r"//Documents//toolinput.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(file_sel, sheet_name='general_report', usecols = "B:B,BA:BA,DS:DS,AP:AP,BN:BN")
first = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ["Jira#", "Plan#", "Clone", "Type", "File"])
first.to_excel(filename,sheet_name='new_sheet_name')
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Do you get error messages (if so, what do they say)? Do you get an excel that is not as expected (if so, how)? Please be specific.

Comment: Please do not upload code as an image ([see here for explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)). Always insert code as formatted text into your question.

Comment: The file is getting created but the selected columns are not getting populated